# C$50 Finance - A Web App for Stock Portfolio Management

Tags: python, cs50

C$50 Finance is a web application built with Flask that allows users to manage their stock portfolios. It enables users to check real-time stock prices, view their portfolio values, and buy/sell stocks.

The full specification of the problem set can be found here:
[C$50 Finance](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/9/finance/).
The code passes all the green checks on `check50`.

**Review Goal:**

General coding comments, style, etc.

**Code:**

app.py:

```
import datetime

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from flask_session import Session
from helpers import apology, is_strong_password, login_required, lookup, usd

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response


@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    # Query to retrieve distinct stock symbols and the sum of shares owned
    # for each stock
    stocks = db.execute(
        """
        SELECT DISTINCT(symbol) AS symbol, SUM(shares_amount) AS shares
        FROM transactions 
        WHERE user_id = ? 
        GROUP BY symbol
        """,
        session["user_id"],
    )

    total_shares_worth = 0

    # Calculate total shares' worth and collect stock prices
    for stock in stocks:
        symbol = stock["symbol"]
        shares = stock["shares"]

        # Lookup stock price
        if symbol:
            stock_info = lookup(stock["symbol"])

            if stock_info:
                stock_price = stock_info["price"]
                total_shares_worth += stock_price * shares
                stock.update({"price": stock_price,
                              "total": stock_price * shares})


    return render_template(
        "index.html",
        stocks=stocks,
        cash=retrieve_cash(),
        grand_total=retrieve_cash() + total_shares_worth,
    )


@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = request.form.get("shares")

        if not symbol or not shares:
            return apology("Please fill in all the fields.")

        # Check if the symbol exists
        stock_info = lookup(symbol)

        if not stock_info:
            return apology("The symbol does not exist.")

        try:
            shares = int(shares)
        except ValueError:
            return apology("Shares must be a whole number.")

        if shares < 1:
            return apology("The number of shares can not be less than 1.")

        # Calculate the total cost of the shares
        cost = shares * stock_info["price"]

        # Check if the user can afford the shares
        cash = retrieve_cash()

        if cash < cost:
            return apology("Insufficient balance.", 403)

        update_cash(cash - cost)
        record_transaction(stock_info, shares, "buy")
        flash("Bought!")
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    return render_template("buy.html")


@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    """Show history of transactions"""
    transactions = db.execute(
        """
        SELECT symbol, shares_amount AS shares, price, date 
        FROM transactions
        WHERE user_id = ?
        """,
        session["user_id"],
    )
    return render_template("history.html", transactions=transactions)


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")

        # Ensure username and password were submitted
        if not password:
            return apology("Please fill all the fields.", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute(
            """
            SELECT * 
            FROM users 
            WHERE username = ?
            """,
            username,
        )

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], password):
            return apology("Invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    """Log user out"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # Redirect user to login form
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    """Get stock quote."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")

        if not symbol:
            return apology("Please fill all the fields.")

        stock_info = lookup(symbol)

        if stock_info:
            return render_template(
                "quoted.html",
                price=stock_info["price"],
                name=stock_info["name"],
                symbol=stock_info["symbol"],
            )
        return apology("Symbol does not exist.")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    return render_template("quote.html")


@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        users = db.execute(
            """
            SELECT * 
            FROM users 
            WHERE username = ?
            """,
            username,
        )

        if not username or not password or not confirmation:
            return apology("Please fill in all fields.")

        if users:
            return apology("Username already exists.")

        res = is_strong_password(password)

        if res != "Success.":
            return apology(res)

        if password != confirmation:
            return apology("Passwords do not match.", 403)

        db.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO users (username, hash) 
            VALUES(?, ?)
            """,
            username,
            generate_password_hash(password),
        )

        return redirect("/login")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    return render_template("register.html")


@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
    """Sell shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = request.form.get("shares")

        if not symbol or not shares:
            return apology("Please input all the fields.")

        try:
            shares = int(shares)
        except ValueError:
            return apology("Shares must be a whole number.")

        # Check if the user owns the stock
        cur_shares = db.execute(
            """
            SELECT SUM(shares_amount) AS total 
            FROM transactions 
            WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?
            """,
            session["user_id"],
            symbol,
        )

        if not cur_shares[0]["total"] or cur_shares[0]["total"] < shares:
            return apology("You don't own enough shares of this stock.")

        if shares < 0:
            return apology("You can't sell negative shares.")

        # Update user's cash balance
        stock_info = lookup(symbol)
        profit = shares * stock_info["price"]
        update_cash(retrieve_cash() + profit) 

        record_transaction(stock_info, -shares, "sold")
        flash("Sold!")
        return redirect("/")

    stocks = db.execute(
        """
            SELECT DISTINCT(symbol) AS symbol 
            FROM transactions 
            WHERE user_id = ? 
            GROUP BY symbol 
            HAVING SUM(shares_amount) > 0
            """,
        session["user_id"],
    )

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    return render_template("sell.html", stocks=stocks)


def retrieve_cash() -> None:
    return db.execute(
                """
                SELECT cash 
                FROM users 
                WHERE id = ?
                """,
                session["user_id"],
            )[0]["cash"]


def update_cash(amount: int) -> None:
    return db.execute(
                """
                UPDATE users
                SET cash = ? 
                WHERE id = ?
                """,
                amount,
                session["user_id"],
            )


def record_transaction(stock_info: dict, shares: int, trans_type: str) -> None:
    db.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO transactions(user_id, symbol, shares_amount, price, date, type)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            """,
            session["user_id"],
            stock_info["name"],
            shares,
            stock_info["price"],
            datetime.datetime.now(),
            trans_type,
        )
```

helpers.py:

```
import datetime
import re
import urllib
import uuid
from functools import wraps

import pytz
import requests
from flask import redirect, render_template, session


def apology(msg: str, code: int = 400):
    """Render message as an apology to user."""

    def escape(s):
        """
        Escape special characters.

        https://github.com/jacebrowning/memegen#special-characters
        """
        for old, new in [
            ("-", "--"),
            (" ", "-"),
            ("_", "__"),
            ("?", "~q"),
            ("%", "~p"),
            ("#", "~h"),
            ("/", "~s"),
            ('"', "''"),
        ]:
            s = s.replace(old, new)
        return s

    return (
        render_template("apology.html", top=code, bottom=escape(msg)),
        code,
    )


def login_required(f):
    """
    Decorate routes to require login.

    http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/viewdecorators/
    """

    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("user_id") is None:
            return redirect("/login")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function


def lookup(symbol: str) -> dict:
    """Look up quote for symbol."""

    # Prepare API request
    symbol = symbol.upper()
    end = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))
    start = end - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

    # Yahoo Finance API
    url = (
        f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(symbol)}"
        f"?period1={int(start.timestamp())}"
        f"&period2={int(end.timestamp())}"
        f"&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    )

    # Query API
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url,
            cookies={"session": str(uuid.uuid4())},
            headers={"User-Agent": "python-requests", "Accept": "*/*"},
        )
        response.raise_for_status()

        # CSV header: Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
        quotes = list(
            csv.DictReader(response.content.decode("utf-8").splitlines())
        )
        quotes.reverse()
        price = round(float(quotes[0]["Adj Close"]), 2)
        return {"name": symbol, "price": price, "symbol": symbol}
    except (requests.RequestException, ValueError, KeyError, IndexError):
        return {}


def usd(value: float) -> str:
    """Format value as USD."""
    return f"${value:,.2f}"


def is_strong_password(password: str) -> str:
    """Verify the strength of 'password'.
    Returns a string indicating the wrong criteria.

    A password is considered strong if:
        8 characters length or more
        1 digit or more
        1 symbol or more
        1 uppercase letter or more
        1 lowercase letter or more
    """

    criteria = [
        (len(password) >= 8, "Password must be at least 8 characters long."), 
        (re.search(r"\d", password), "Password must contain at least one digit."),
        (re.search(r"[A-Z]", password), "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter."),
        (re.search(r"[a-z]", password), "Password must contain at least one lowercase letter."),
        (re.search(r"\W", password), "Password must contain at least one special character"),
    ]

    for cond, msg in criteria:
        if not cond:
            return msg

    return "Success."
```

The code was formatted with `black` and `isort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code was formatted with black and isort.

Yes, thank you, I noticed that at once upon reading these imports:

```
# [2nd group]
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
...

# [3rd group]
from flask_session import Session
from helpers import ...
```

I was about to consult pypi for "flask_session" which I'm not familiar with,
and then I noticed that the posted "helpers" and the not-posted "flask_session"
are definitely part of your project rather than a published pypi project.
Kudos for clear communication.

---

## safely importable

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# ...
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# ...
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Configure CS50 Library to use SQLite database
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
```

That first line is bog standard and should remain as-is.
The filter, I imagine, is pretty safe, as are the `.config` assignments.

I'm not familiar with `Session()`, but I worry about its FS read/write needs.
And the `SQL()` call will definitely write to
[CWD](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd)
and perhaps require finding a readable .db file there.

In other words this code will produce CWD side effects, and may
have "bailing due to fatal error" side effects if it can't read its favorite file.

Avoid side effecting code at top level of a module.
Bury such code in a helper function.
Use an `if __name__ ...` guard to run it conditionally.
We want it to be safe for other modules to `import` this module,
without side effects. For example, a
[test suite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
may want to test some helper within this module.

BTW, a nit on docstrings: You begin them with an English sentence, and that's great.
Each sentence should end with a `.` period. Whatever.

---

## cite your reference

The `after_request` function is, on the whole, terrific.
Single responsibility, short, sweet, pretty clear.

There *has* been a fair amount of drift over the years
in what origin servers, proxies, and clients support.
Caching is a regrettably complex topic.
Maintenance engineers commonly have to investigate cache-related problem reports.
The doctest / comments would benefit from any descriptions you'd care to add,
describing research you've already done while authoring this code:

- IETF spec(s) you adhere to
- URL of someone's blog on the topic that you relied on
- list of server versions and proxy versions you've validated against
- pointer to integration tests within this repo that verify correct behavior

---

## sql details

```
        SELECT DISTINCT(symbol) ...
        FROM ...
        GROUP BY symbol
```

Sorry, I'm not getting the DISTINCT here.
We're GROUPing by symbol, right?
So the backend is *guaranteeing* we will only get unique `symbol`s in the result.

Maybe this is leftover from early exploratory debugging queries.
Anyway, recommend you elide "DISTINCT".
Similarly down in `sell()`.

Also, kudos on properly using bind vars, and thereby dodging
the spectre of Little Bobby Tables.

## null guard

```
        if symbol:
```

Consider tacking on a WHERE ... AND conjunct,
to guarantee that only "good" symbols are returned by the backend.

## hoist common subexpression

```
    return render_template(
        ... ,
        cash=retrieve_cash(),
        grand_total=retrieve_cash() + ... ,
    )
```

There's an opportunity to assign a temp var,
so you make a single backend call instead of two.

Alternatively, possibly a
[@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)
decorator on that `retrieve_cash` helper would be attractive.

---

## minimize indent

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
```

Consider conditionally dealing with GET first and `return`ing a result.

Then by the time you get to the bulk of the code,
you can unconditionally deal with POST,
saving four spaces of indent.

---

## extract validation helper

```
            shares = int(shares)
```

In a few places you check for fractional shares.
Consider creating a helper that would let you write

```
            shares = need_whole_number(shares)
```

and in the error case it would `raise` a FractionalSharesError
to let a top-level `try` report the appropriate apology().

---

## selling stock you don't own

I don't understand the `[0]` dereference:

```
        cur_shares = db.execute(
            """
            SELECT SUM(shares_amount) AS total 
            FROM transactions 
            WHERE user_id = ? AND symbol = ?
            """,
            session["user_id"],
            symbol,
        )
        if not cur_shares[0]["total"]
```

If `symbol` is some non-existant XYZZY,
then we get zero result rows and the `[0]`
leads to IndexError.

---

## standard time zone

In `record_transaction` we record `now()` in the transactions table.
It's not obvious to me that we're recording UTC seconds since 1970.
Maybe we are?
There's no comments or unit tests to help me understand
whether running the webserver in EDT or PDT time zone
would affect what's stored in the database.

It's common to develop against sqlite and then later deploy
in production against e.g. postgres, where different clients
may be in diverse geographic locations / timezones, hence the concern.

---

This codebase appears to achieve its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Documentation for `flask_session` can be found here: [Flask-Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Great points as always.